# How to restrict facebook default page to be displayed while login using facebook sdk

Tags: iphone, facebook

While using auto-login from native facebook, if I get logged out from native app then session won't work and facebook default login page get displayed. How could I detect that after which delegate or function of FBSession class is called after which the facebook default login page get displayed and restrict it to get displayed?

This is what I am doing to do a auto login

```
CacheToken = [[FBTokenCache alloc]init];
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"email,user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins", nil];


self.fbsession = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:@"484473011575776"
                                              permissions:permissions
                                          urlSchemeSuffix:nil
                                       tokenCacheStrategy:CacheToken];

(fbsession is the object of Facebook SDK class FBSession)
[FBSession setActiveSession:self.fbsession];


[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                                  [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user facebook old sdk. In facebook.m just allow your app to open within app i.e trySafari = FALSE; and tryFBApp = FALSE;

I am using this.
Hope this will also help you.